# How should I set parameters "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb" in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Did I set correct? everytime when I run the program, it will always show errors：

`Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 5. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value.`

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from graphframes import *

sc = SparkContext("local")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql('SET spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=9000')
sqlContext.sql('SET spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the `setConf()` if you want to add configuration to [SqlContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.setConf).

But if you want to add the configuration to SparkContext you can use the simple set function like this:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MY_APP') \
                          .set('spark.executor.cores', 4) \
                          .set('spark.executor.memory', '16g') \
                          .set('spark.driver.memory', '16g') \
                          .set('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', 1024) \
                          .set('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', 'true') \
                          .set('spark.shuffle.service.enabled', 'true') \
                          .set('spark.shuffle.service.port', 7337) \
                          .set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', 250) \
                          .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

And then add setConf to your context:

```
sqlContext = SqlContext(sc).setConf("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", 9000)
```

Comment: Thanks. I do like this, but still have some errors. For example 比如`java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2@133d095a rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@961ff87[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 497]`

Comment: I don't know why it works well with test data(small part), but with who graph, pagerank doesn't work.